# How do I update git to the latest version?

Tags: git, google-compute-engine

I am using git version 2.1.4 on GCE.

```
$ git --version
git version 2.1.4
```

I would like to update to the latest version, but it was not updated when I executed the following command.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Is my way wrong?

---

After that,I tried the following but it got an error.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa
sudo apt-get update
```

The following error has occurred.

```
W: ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/candidate/ubuntu/dists/jessie/mai‌​n/… 404 Not Found
W: ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu/dists/jessie/main/… 404 Not Found
```

I found out how to fix with Ubuntu, but do you know how to fix GCE (debian)?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/449977/which-ppa-has-the-most-current-version-of-git-for-12-04-ppagit-core-ppa-is-out#449999

Comment: Try this:
https://gist.github.com/derhuerst/1b15ff4652a867391f03

Answer (score 5):

Add the Git Maintainers repository to get the latest Git version.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, I could not update it.

The following error has occurred.
W: http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/candidate/ubuntu/dists/jessie/main/binary-amd64/Packages   404  Not Found
W: http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu/dists/jessie/main/binary-amd64/Packages 404  Not Found

I found out how to fix with ubuntu, but do you know how to fix GCE (debian)?

Answer (score 0):

In ubuntu 16.04 the following worked for me. before running the below commands my git version is 2.7, now it's the latest version

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:git-core/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git -y
```